# Call several different JavaScript within AjaxLink one after the other

Tags: ajax, wicket

When I click on an AjaxLink, I would like to have a validation via JavaScript on the client side first (because the LocalStorage is queried) and then depending on the result, further JavaScript calls are made. How can i achieve this?
In a pseudo code it would look like this:

```
new AjaxLink<>("myId", myModel) {

    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        boolean isCounterValid = target.appendJavaScript(checkCounter()); // i know that this is not possible, therefore pseudo code
        if(isCounterValid) {
            target.appendJavaScript(someOtherJavaScript());
        }
        else {
            target.appendJavaScript(anotherJavaScript());
        }
    }

    private String checkCounter() {
        return "var count = window.localStorage.getItem('myCounter'); return count !== 1;";
    }

    private String someOtherJavaScript() {
        return "change something";
    }

    private String anotherJavaScript() {
        return "change other thing";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send extra request parameters with the Ajax call when the link is clicked. For that you should override  `updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes)` method of AjaxLink:

```
@Override
protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes)
{
   attributes.getDynamicExtraParameters().add("var count = window.localStorage.getItem('myCounter'); return [{\"name\":\"count\", \"value\": count}]");
}
```

This way inside `AjaxLink#onClick()` you can read the count via:

```
int count = getRequest().getRequestParameters().getParameterValue("count").toInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

AJAX components and behaviors can customize AJAX attributes overriding updateAjaxAttributes and using a custom implementation of AjaxCallListener which exposes different method to hook into the AJAX request cycle. In you case you could use AjaxCallListener#getBeforeSendHandler.
For a full introduction to this topic (with examples) see user guide:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_ajax_request_attributes_and_call_listeners